# simple html dom failed to open stream for a site

Tags: php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to parse throught http://whatismyip.com page and get my location (state and country). The data seems to be inside `<table class="table">` tags, so i'm looking for "table".
  But I get a mistake `Warning: file_get_contents(https://whatismyip.com): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden in C:\xampp4\htdocs\scraping\libs\simple_html_dom.php on line 1081`

Can't figure out what's wrong.

```
 <?php
        require_once('libs/simple_html_dom.php');
        $html=new simple_html_dom();

        $html->load_file('https://whatismyip.com');

        $element=$html->find("table");


    ?>
```

Comment: Looks like whatismyip.com is blocking you from doing it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That website is checking the `User-Agent` header of the request but PHP doesn't send any (by default). You'll have to "impersonate" a browser:

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'header' => array('User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; rv:2.2) Gecko/20110201'),
    ),
));

$html = file_get_contents('http://whatismyip.com/', false, $context);

// do what you want with the $html
```

A better (and faster) option would be to use some library for this. I've used [GeoIP2-php](https://github.com/maxmind/GeoIP2-php) before but I'm sure there are more.

Comment: Great, Worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

basicly your exemple it good but the mistakes here is simple html dom classes not working with Https so try another method

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://whatismyip.com");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://whatismyip.com");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; rv:2.2) Gecko/20110201');
$str = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

and then use your code

```
    $html->load_file($str);
    $element=$html->find("table");
```

**Edit** Adding User-agent to emulate a real navigator (thanks to ShiraNai7)

Comment: This also results in *HTTP 403 Forbidden* since the `User-Agent` header is still missing from the request.

Comment: yes probably the User-Agent have a big impact here i recommand you code so mutch , for my code i just give another way to write the solution thanks for comment @ShiraNai7

Comment: Adding `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; rv:2.2) Gecko/20110201');` makes this code work too :)

Answer (score 3):

try changing the user agent using below command -

```
ini_set("user_agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0");
```

it will work fine then!